# For a component in React with Reux, how to not fire mouse event in one case and how to fire mouse event in another case

Tags: reactjs, redux, mouseevent

I have a `Photo` component, it looks like this:

```
class Photo extends Component {
    mouseEnter() {
        //some actions
    }

    render() {
        <img src={this.props.src} onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter}>
    }
}
```

`Photo` is reused in other components. In some components, I want to fire the `onMouseEnter` event of `Photo`, but in some other components, I want to not fire the `onMouseEnter` event.

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
    render() {
        <Photo {...this.props}></Photo>
        //want to fire mouse enter event of Photo
    }
}

class ComponentB extends Component {
    render() {
        <Photo {...this.props}></Photo>
        //want to not fire mouse enter event of Photo
    }
}
```

How to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React props passed into your component as an attribute with no value get passed as a `true` boolean. For example `<Photo useMouseEnter />` will give you `this.props.useMouseEnter === true`. Using this you can control wether `mouseEnter` is used or not.

```
class Photo extends Component {
    mouseEnter() {
        //some actions
    }

    render() {
        <img
            src={this.props.src} 
            onMouseEnter={this.props.useMouseEnter ?
                this.mouseEnter : null}
        >
    }
}
```

The turnary operation in onMouseEnter will pass `this.mouseEnter` if `this.props.useMouseEnter` exists otherwise `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new prop like `hireMouseEvent` and pass it to the `<Photo>`

```
mouseEnter() {
    if(this.props.hireMouseEvent) {
    }
}
```

Add it, when you render your component

```
<Photo hireMouseEvent={false}></Photo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Don't forget to bind **onMouseEnter** to Photo class.

When you want to receive events from `Photo` component pass in onMouseEnter handler to `Photo` component.

```js
class Photo extends React.Component {
 onMouseEnter = evt => {
  !this.props.onMouseEnter && this.props.onMouseEnter(evt)
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <img
    src={this.props.src}
    onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}
   />
  )
 }
}
```